# Convert BitmapImage to Icon without saving into disk

Tags: c#, wpf, image, bitmap, icons

Iam using this code to generate bitmap from string. Now i need to convert this bitmap into ICO or icon and below method is not working it causes error when i use System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Icon error is Null Refrence Exception. and if i use any other format that error resolved and new error arise in m_notifyIcon that cannot use this as image. what to do...

```
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = TextToBitmap("This");//return bitmap 
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Icon);
        BitmapImage imgg = new BitmapImage();
        imgg.BeginInit();
        imgg.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray());
        imgg.EndInit();
        //img.Source = imgg;
        Icon io = new System.Drawing.Icon(ms);
        m_notifyIcon.Icon = io;
```

Answer (score 1):

Got answer to my question.

```
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = TextToBitmap("String");
        System.IntPtr ich = bmp.GetHicon();
        System.Drawing.Icon io = System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(ich);
        m_notifyIcon.Icon = io;
```

get Bitmap iamge use IntPtr and use the above code...